# Send data to external source in Smartface App Studio

Tags: mobile, smartface.io

I wanna know about "how can I send a data to external database for example MSSQL, MySQL or any?"
Is it possible? (even if I use some 3rd party library)

Answer (score 0):

You should use network objects, You can not directly connect the databases. 
You can use WebService (SOAP ) or WebClient ( JSON ) objects to manage your datas.

You can read more info from http://developer.smartface.io/hc/en-us/categories/200058238

Data & Network section is what you want to learn.

Smartface.io Team